# Programatically build SQL insert strings based on existing data

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, node.js

I have a SQL Server production database with a lot of tables and data. I want for a specific record in table A to get all the related records in tables B,C,D so that I can insert that data in my local database for debugging purposes.

Ultimately I would like to run all the generated INSERTs on my local database. I cannot create a DB link or stuff like that. And I cannot have my application insert that data in my local database, as it will run on a production server. So my only solution is to dump the data in INSERT statements.

So my idea was to create a small app (preferably in Nodejs or Java) that will query that prod database's each table, get the related rows, and build INSERT statements by hand. The problem with this approach would be that I would have to build the insert statement by hand and because there's quite a few tables and a lot of columns, that would be tedious. Also I would have to account for all data types.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Build up the SQL using ? to indicated where a parameter will go then in your query / execute pass the parameters as a comma delimited array this will prevent all the escaping you would need to do inline.

Comment: Can you connect to production database via jdbc?

Comment: If you are able to connect to your production DB using Java, then you can have 2 different data sources,  one for prod and one for local. And can easily transfer data

Comment: I can connect to the production database via jdbc, but I cannot connect both to the production and my local databases

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has `Generate Scripts` functionality. Using that, you can export the schema, data, and other details from your database in SQL file. 

>> Task >> Generate Scripts >> Select Objects >> Set Options >> Export`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is what I'm currently doing, but I want to do it `programatically` because there's a lot of relational data linked to a single record that I want to dump

Comment: I need for one specific row in table A, to get the row, plus all the relational data from tables B,C,D and for B also get other relational data from X,Y,Z. But I want only rows related to that first row in table A

Comment: For that, I think creating your own programming script will do, no need to use node.js, Java is good enough, if you are comfortable with that language